# PhpStorm has a problem when referencing to a Type named "Resource"

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStorm version: 2022.2.3 (Build #PS-222.4345.15, built on October 5, 2022)

I have following class:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\API\Resources;

final class ConfiguredResourceFinder implements ResourceFinder
{
    /** @var $resources Resource[] */
    private array $resources;

    public function find(string $key): Resource
    {
        foreach ($this->resources as $resource) {
            $resource-> // public method suggestion from type Resource not appearing
        }
    }
}
```

And following interface in the same namespace:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\API\Resources;

interface Resource
{
    public function getKey(): string;
}
```

When I type `$resource->`, no method suggestion `getKey()` is coming.

[image]

But when I change the Type, for example to `/** @var $resources Foo[] */`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\API\Resources;

interface Foo
{
    public function getKey(): string;
}
```

I receive suggestions:

[image]

Any idea why this is not working with the `Resource` interface? I already invalidated the PhpStorm cache.

Comment: For issues like this, please always state your PhpStorm version.

Comment: That's supposed to be working in current 2022.3.1 version (for a while actually) ( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15619 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-55367 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42656). But I have checked and got the same. So I suggest you submit a ticket to the PhpStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI together with the code sample

Comment: P.S. If you add the following line `use App\API\Resources\Resource;` it will start working correctly (but obviously this line is not needed since we are in the same namespace).